# Swift bridging of an NSError function to a throwable function not working

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I'm using an init function (from an AWS SDK) in an Obj-c file with this signature:

```
- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionaryValue error:(NSError **)error;
```

Which bridges to this signature template:

[image]

Note that it is still suggesting an `error` parameter of type `()` which of course makes no sense.  Why isn't it correctly removing the `error` from the swift signature and/or why is the `error` parameter `()`?  The helpie correctly says it `throws`:

[image]

**EDIT:**
Turns out the problem is being caused by the superclass deprecating an old signature:

```
- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionaryValue __attribute__((deprecated("Replaced by -initWithDictionary:error:")));
```

If I comment out that deprecation it works fine, looks like this might be a bug in Swift's bridging of Obj-c

Comment: Which Xcode version are you using? my Xcode7.1.1 works as expected.

Comment: Still happens in 7.1.1 unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite a bug, but admittedly an oddity.

In Swift, it's not legal to have a function that's overloaded by whether it `throws`:

```
func foo() {}
func foo() throws {} // invalid redeclaration of `foo`
```

An ObjC method with a final `NSError` out-parameter gets converted into a `throws` method in Swift. So if you have two ObjC methods that differ only in the addition of an error parameter, it can't import using Swift error syntax.

What happens instead is that the `NSError` parameter gets turned into a `throws`, but its parameter label remains as a `Void` (aka `()`) parameter to preserve method signature uniqueness. You call it like this:

```
// signature
func foo(thing: String, error: ()) throws
// call site
try foo("bar", error: ()) // enclose in do/catch as desired, or use `try!`
```

In theory, deprecation should cause the non-erroring version of the ObjC method to not be visible in Swift (and thus allow the erroring version to import with Swift error syntax). Maybe that applies only to some of the specific deprecation attributes that you get from the `AvailabilityMacros.h` macros? (That might be worth [filing a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com) about.)

Another alternative for making sure the non-erroring ObjC method doesn't import is marking it with `NS_SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE`.